# Drop and create table in one command

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, create-table

do you know why below code is wrong on ms sql server?

```
DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] database.table1,
create table table1 (...)
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, for what possible scenario would you use it? The result of these commands would be basically a `truncate`.

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? Are you getting an error? Please take some time to read [mcve].

Comment: @Utsav Changing the schema of an existing table?

Comment: @MorganThrapp - Yep that could be a scenario.

Comment: `BEGIN TRY` / `END TRY` and `create table` inside...

Comment: I have underlying "database"

I just want to write script: if the table is exists drop, and create new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's `SQL Server 2016` syntax.
For earlier versions, you can use the `EXISTS` function to check whether your table exists in the `sys.tables` list and drop it if it does. Then create a new table.

Somewhat like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1' AND type = 'U') DROP TABLE table1;
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    ...
    ...
);
```

Comment: For the uninitiated - [DROP IF EXISTS – new thing in SQL Server 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35918914/692942)

Comment: Technically [@henrik-staun-poulsen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106843/henrik-staun-poulsen) actually [answers the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35919033/692942) *(remember you asked "do you know why below code is wrong on ms sql server?")*, while this is helpful it shouldn't be the accepted answer. It wouldn't work because you were trying to use SQL Server 2016 syntax in whatever SQL Server version you are running.

Comment: Since `SQL Server 2016` is not yet commercially available, it was safe to assume that he is using previous version of SQL Server; hence my answer. Anyways I have edited my answer now to reflect the correct sense.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is only valid on [SQL Server 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/), which is not released yet.

Are you sure that you are using that version?
Otherwise you could use the IF Exists that [@pradeep-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252228/pradeep-kumar) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918914/692942).